# PLSQL DBMS_SCHEDULER wait for response

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql

I've created a DBMS_SCHEDULER to run a batch-script from PL/SQL.
The script starts as expected but now I need to find a way to pause my PL/SQL code until the batch-script has done it's work. My batch does something like

- Read csv-files of amount x
- Copy the csv-values into an existing Excel-file
- Zip those files.

After that my PL/SQL code should start again. The batch-process can take from few seconds up to one hour depends on the amount of values. Is there a way how I can pause my script and wait for a response?

Here my code

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ('myjob',
                              job_action            => 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE',
                              number_of_arguments   => 3,
                              job_type              => 'executable',
                              enabled               => FALSE);

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myjob', 1, '/q');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myjob', 2, '/c');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('myjob', 3, 'c:\temp\test.bat');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable ('myjob');
END;
```

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: @APC I'm using Oracle 11g. My batch does something like Read csv-files of amount x / Copy the csv-values into an existing Excel-file / Zip those files. After that my PL/SQL code should start again. The batch-process can take from few seconds up to one hour depends on the amount of values

Comment: @APC Unfortunately it didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a table with one column which will hold the value for scheduler execution. Put all the PL/SQL code in a if-else which checks for the value in this table. If the value is true then the code will execute as required, if the value is false then it just completes the execution without doing anything. So when your batch script starts update the value in the table as false so every time the scheduler runs it will see false and exit without doing anything, at the end of batch script update the value to true so the next scheduler run will execute as required.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had the same idea yesterday and it worked as expected